# which library is linked when i am using stdio.h,conio.h

Tags: c, linux

see when ever we are going to use any library at that time we include one .h file in our application & at compiling that application we link that library. if  that library is .so then link at run time.

Now my question is in any system when i am including basic header file like stdio.h conio.h string.h at that time which library is going to link with my program.?

Is it static or dynamic.?

how can i install it in ma system.? any documentation for that?

we are not linking that library still does that library automatically link.?

Comment: try `ldd <binaryName>` to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libc.so` is the standard library (dynamically linked) of linux (currently **libc.so.6**)

Comment: Some version of libc, yes. see more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library

Answer (score 0):

The implementations for those functions are usually found in the libc directly, e.g. libc.so.6 or msvcrt90.dll.

Comment: *Every* operating system beyond a certain complexity has a libc.